# Wordpress page navigation within posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page template in wordpress that only shows posts from a specific category with ID 972. I've limited it so that it displays 8 posts on the page. I was wondering if it would be possible to display page navigation at the bottom, so that I could go to the next post page **ONLY** from the posts with category ID 972. Is this possible?

EDIT:
the `post_nav_link();` function doesn't work for me...

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: that's supposes to say `posts_nav_link();`..sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible to do as the link only works on categories / archived pages. The link goes to something like URL/category/page/[page#]

Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, ok. My bad, interpreted that wrong.

I had this snippet floating around (not from me, no idea where I found it):

```
function pagination( $query, $baseURL )
{
    $page = $query->query_vars["paged"];
    if ( !$page ) $page = 1;
    $qs = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] ? "?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] : "";
    // Only necessary if there's more posts than posts-per-page
    if ( $query->found_posts > $query->query_vars["posts_per_page"] ) {
        echo '<ul class="paging">';
        // Previous link?
        if ( $page > 1 ) {
            echo '<li class="previous"><a href="'.$baseURL.'page/'.($page-1).'/'.$qs.'">« Previous page</a></li>';
        }
        // Loop through pages
        for ( $i=1; $i <= $query->max_num_pages; $i++ ) {
            // Current page or linked page?
            if ( $i == $page ) {
                echo '<li class="active"><span>'.$i.'</span></li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="'.$baseURL.'page/'.$i.'/'.$qs.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        // Next link?
        if ( $page < $query->max_num_pages ) {
            echo '<li class="next"><a href="'.$baseURL.'page/'.($page+1).'/'.$qs.'">Next page »</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

It takes a query object (your category query) and a base url (your archive page) and generates a pagination. Maybe this works for you.

Comment: This has potential to work. I'm just curious, where would the links go to? Because they would have to point to the archives links, and that's not what I want, since the archived page is using a default theme template, while the portfolio page is using a 'portfolio template'. +1 for the help!

Comment: You have to provide the URL you're using this at. This might be a custom template you built. I'm using it this way: <?php pagination($news_archive, get_permalink($post→ID)) ?> (where $new_archive is my query object).

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. There's a difference between a "next_post_link()", which gives a link to the NEXT POST, and a post_nav_link(), which gives a link to the next page of posts. I do not think what I am trying to do is possible with Wordpress. Only in archives is this possible. Thanks for trying, though.